# Can't fix: RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

Currently, I’m trying to replicate a DeblurGanV2 network. At the moment, I’m working on performing the training. Here is my current status of my trainings pipeline:

```
from torch.autograd import Variable
torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(mode=True)
total_generator_loss = 0
total_discriminator_loss = 0
psnr_score = 0.0
used_loss_function = 'wgan_gp_loss'
for epoch in range(n_epochs):

      #set to train mode
      generator.train(); discriminator.train()
      tqdm_bar = tqdm(train_loader, desc=f'Training Epoch {epoch} ', total=int(len(train_loader)))
      for batch_idx, imgs in enumerate(tqdm_bar):
        
        #load imgs to cpu
        blurred_images = imgs["blurred"].cuda()
        sharped_images = imgs["sharp"].cuda()
        
        # generator output
        deblurred_img = generator(blurred_images)
    
        # denormalize
        with torch.no_grad():
          denormalized_blurred = denormalize(blurred_images)
          denormalized_sharp = denormalize(sharped_images)
          denormalized_deblurred = denormalize(deblurred_img)
    
        # get D's output
        sharp_discriminator_out = discriminator(sharped_images)
        deblurred_discriminator_out = discriminator(deblurred_img)
    
        # set critic_updates
        if used_loss_function== 'wgan_gp_loss':
          critic_updates = 5
        else:
            critic_updates = 1
    
        #train discriminator
        discriminator_loss = 0
        for i in range(critic_updates):
          discriminator_optimizer.zero_grad()
          # train discriminator on real and fake
          if used_loss_function== 'wgan_gp_loss':
            gp_lambda = 10
            alpha = random.random()
            interpolates = alpha * sharped_images + (1 - alpha) * deblurred_img
            interpolates_discriminator_out = discriminator(interpolates)
            kwargs = {'gp_lambda': gp_lambda,
                       'interpolates': interpolates,
                       'interpolates_discriminator_out': interpolates_discriminator_out,
                       'sharp_discriminator_out': sharp_discriminator_out,
                       'deblurred_discriminator_out': deblurred_discriminator_out
                        }
            wgan_loss_d, gp_d = wgan_gp_loss('D', **kwargs)
            discriminator_loss_per_update = wgan_loss_d + gp_d
    
          discriminator_loss_per_update.backward(retain_graph=True)
          discriminator_optimizer.step()
          discriminator_loss += discriminator_loss_per_update.item()
```

But when I run this code, I receive the following error message:

> RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.cuda.FloatTensor [1, 512, 4, 4]] is at version 2; expected version 1 instead. Hint: the backtrace further above shows the operation that failed to compute its gradient. The variable in question was changed in there or anywhere later. Good luck!

> RuntimeError Traceback (most recent call last) in () 62 # discriminator_loss_per_update = gan_loss_d 63 —> 64
> discriminator_loss_per_update.backward(retain_graph=True) 65
> discriminator_optimizer.step() 66 discriminator_loss +=
> discriminator_loss_per_update.item()
>
> 1 frames /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/tensor.py in
> backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs) 243
> create_graph=create_graph, 244 inputs=inputs) → 245
> torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph,
> inputs=inputs) 246 247 def register_hook(self, hook):
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/autograd/init.py in
> backward(tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph,
> grad_variables, inputs) 145 Variable.execution_engine.run_backward(
> 146 tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs, → 147
> allow_unreachable=True, accumulate_grad=True) # allow_unreachable flag
> 148 149

Unfortunately, I can’t really trace the in-place operation that would cause this error. Does anybody maybe has an idea or advice for me? I would appreciate any input :slight_smile:

Answer (score 0):

try changing the last line to:

```py
discriminator_loss = discriminator_loss + discriminator_loss_per_update.item()
```